# Prestashop store - Paypal charges shipping fees on (virtual product) i.e (Giftcard)

Tags: paypal, prestashop

We are charging the fee $5.50 on the voucher. We shouldn’t. i.e there is no freight and there should be no fee Paypal charges shipping fees on (virtual product) i.e (Giftcard)

Any thoughts ? how to make free shipping fee for virtual products ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a discount voucher, or created a free carrier, but available only for virtual products.

Regards